# How to handle Untrusted Certificate Selenium Webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm using Selenium to access a site, but I constantly get ***Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead***. I searched all over the Internet for a solution to my problem, but the message to accept the certificate manually continues to appear.
I'm using:

- Firefox: 85.0.1 (64-bit)
- Geckodriver
- Python language

I tested several solutions such as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
#capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('xxxxxxxxx')
```

And,

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('xxxxxxxxx')
```

I also tried solutions based on creating a new profile in Firefox.
The question is: **How can I automate the acceptance of a website's certificate when I launch Firefox with Selenium (Python programming language)?**

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/acceptInsecureCerts

```
from selenium import webdriver
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't solve... The 2nd solution is the one I tried and the 1st solution raises WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

Comment: @Raphael updated the answer use the second option

Comment: its same solution like yours instead of capability use desired_capability=capability

Comment: if you still get that error then use capabilities['marionette'] = True also

Comment: I hope your solution can help someone, however for me the problem of the warning persists...

Comment: @Raphael did you tried the new code ? it works perfectly for me

Comment: try installing selenium 4

Comment: `pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7`

Comment: Added the full code just copy paste the full code and try by changing false to true and true to false for accept cert

Comment: Dont change marionette. Else you will get firefox not reached errlr

Comment: I upgraded Selenium to 4.0.0a6 thanks to: "pip install selenium==4.0.0a6.post2". I just confirmed and your code works, but for the site I want to access it doesn't...

Comment: I installed Selenium 4.0.0a7 but I still can't access directly the website I want.

Comment: What error dies the site shows what kind of certificate error is it

Comment: The error code is SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER, related to SSL certificates

Comment: i tried with driver.get("https://untrusted-root.badssl.com/")
driver.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/") both works , untrusted-root give the unknown issuer error

Comment: Both work for me too, but not the site I want to access... Does it have to do with the site or the type of certificate?

Comment: @Raphael is it a public site ?

Comment: No, it's a client site, I access the site through VPN... But when I run the program if I manually click in "Accept the Risk and Continue", Firefox accesses the site.

Comment: what happens if you also add acceptSslCerts:true capability

Comment: Nothing changes... Right now I'm trying to solve this with a new FF Profile

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem creating a new Firefox Profile and executing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
#Path to the Firefox Profile directory
options.profile = r'C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\x.x'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://xxxxx')
```